# Android - How do I create an email body from a file that contains css and html?

Tags: html, css, email, android-intent

I have looked and found lots of great answers on how to load html into a body of an email Intent, but couldn't find how to load a file that contain css and html.  I have a program that shows a webview where I display the file using:

webView.loadUrl("file://" + htmlManager.htmlFilePath(HtmlManager.myHtmlFile));

I have the email loading html using

Uri data = Uri.parse("mailto:?subject=" + subject + "&body=" + Html.fromHtml(htmlString));

but can I use the same file I used for the loadUrl for the body of the email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this site css is not able to be rendered in android email bodies

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/