# How to apply CSS to email body text in Android?

Tags: android, html, css, email, android-intent

I am sending an email through intent, here I want to set CSS styles to the body of email, I have already referred many questions and answers on Stack and found below code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("text/html");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"me@mydomain.com"});
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "I would like to buy the following");
                intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "sending mail"));
```

but this code sets only text in email body and skips my css styles, how do I achieve that? I want to set background color, text size, text color to the email body all through Android intent.

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer on this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344468/android-how-do-i-create-an-email-body-from-a-file-that-contains-css-and-html) post, according to this gmail doesn't support css in Head and Body tag in html.

Also see [this](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) link for more about Css support in browsers.

Answer (score 0):

save the html as a file and add your css html attachment to a list of Uri objects and add this line:-

intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);

Comment: i want the text to be displayed in body of the mail , also can u please elaborate your code to make it more clear.

Comment: i have tried this but what it does is , it attach the html file in the mail , where as i want to apply formatting in body text which i think not possible in gmail other mail agent too. thanks for your answer.